# Set radio button checked - label doesn't change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

I'd like to remove and set a radio button checked. In the snippet it works like a charm but on localhost it doesn't. The input gets checked though but the label doesn't change. If I set another radio button (e.q. #b) as checked, the label changes.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/w41q983r/) is the JSFiddle.

```js
$('#a').attr('checked', false);
$('#a').attr('checked', true);
```

```css
input:checked + label {
  /* background-color, font-size, etc. */
}
```

Comment: Please provide a JS fiddle or something similar

Comment: It's would be difficult to answer to this question without your `html`

Comment: `In the snippet it works like a charm but on localhost it doesn't` Normally this is because you've forgotten to use a document.ready handler as the snippet editor/jsFiddle includes this for you by default. Without seeing all of your relevant code we cannot answer this accurately, though.

Comment: checked should be a set/unset with `.prop` not sure that is cause for anything, though.

Comment: @user3154108 using prop works, do you know why?

Comment: Cause you end up with two checked radio buttons

Comment: @ogm58191 your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/Lh7a0eqr/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, my code doesn't work. As I said, I have to **remove and add again** checked to a radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.prop` instead of `.attr`, latter will result in html like `checked=false" not a removel of checked property.

Edit: The underlying problem is that OP used `.attr` on two radios of the same name, `.attr` does not ever remove the porperty checked. That ends up giving you two radios which are checked, that is invalid.

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer. Sure `prop()` is better practice, but the OPs logic should have worked with `attr()` (and does: https://jsfiddle.net/h9uzjnkp/) Therefore there must be another underlying problem

Comment: See the edit. The problem is that `checked=false` as attribute in the html is still considered a checked radios, and if you have two checked radios of the same name your browser ends up not checking any cause the html is semantically invalid.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The problem only occurs if checked is set at by default (html) then removed and added again (see https://jsfiddle.net/w41q983r/). In no other case do I have this problem.